# how do i get keydown to input only once?

Tags: pygame, key, inventory

hey so im pretty new to python and im trying to make this game. its a 2d top down action game. i added an inventory, yet  i have to hold <kbd>e</kbd> for it to keep open, how do i make it so keydown inputs only once and the inventory keeps open?

i apologize if the code looks messy.

the code i need  help for:

```py
win.fill(green)
win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
win.blit(tree, (xtree, ytree))
win.blit(tree1, (xtree1, ytree1))
win.blit(tree2, (xtree2, ytree2))
win.blit(rocka, (xrock, yrock))
win.blit(rockb, (xrock1, yrock1))
win.blit(rockc, (xrock2, yrock2))
win.blit(i, (200, 530))
win.blit(top, (100, 2))

def openinventory():
    global w
    win.blit(border, (10, 10))
    win.blit(border, (770, 10))
    win.blit(border1, (10, 270))
    win.blit(border1, (770, 280))
    win.blit(border2, (10, 590))
    win.blit(border2, (10, 10))
    win.blit(border2, (10, 250))
    win.blit(border2, (15, 270))
    win.blit(islot, (20, 20))
    win.blit(islot, (20, 100))
    win.blit(islot, (20, 175))
    win.blit(islot, (90, 20))
    win.blit(islot, (90, 100))
    win.blit(islot, (90, 175))
    win.blit(islot, (160, 20))
    win.blit(islot, (160, 100))
    win.blit(islot, (160, 175))
    win.blit(i1, (240, 20))
    win.blit(border, (230, 10))
    win.blit(i2, (14, 270))

    if woodmat == 1:
        win.blit(woodmat3, w)
        if w > (10, 10) and w > (200, 0):
            w = (20, 455)
    if woodmat == 2:
        win.blit(woodmat6, w)
        if w > (10, 10) and w > (200, 0):
            w = (20, 455)
    if woodmat == 3 or woodmat > 3:
        win.blit(woodmat9, w)
        if w > (10, 10) and w > (200, 0):
            w = (20, 455)
    if rockmat == 1:
        win.blit(rockmat2, (100, 455))
    if rockmat == 2 or rockmat > 2:
        win.blit(rockmat4, (100, 455))
    if rockmat == 3 or rockmat > 3:
        win.blit(rockmat6, (100, 455))

# here it is:
if keys[pygame.K_e]:
    openinventory()
```

heres the full code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 150, 15)
blue = (0, 0, 255)


def game_loop():
    global w

    w = 20, 455

    w_width = 800
    w_height = 600

    xtree = 390
    ytree = 80

    xtree1 = 90
    ytree1 = 280

    xtree2 = 590
    ytree2 = 140

    xrock = 215
    yrock = 185

    xrock1 = 690
    yrock1 = 340

    xrock2 = 400
    yrock2 = 300

    woodmat = 0
    rockmat = 0

    x = 400
    y = 400

    pygame.display.set_caption("Dragon Quest 2")
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((w_width, w_height))
    icon = pygame.image.load("icon.gif")
    pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    man = pygame.image.load("man.gif")
    manright = pygame.image.load("manleft.gif")
    manleft = pygame.image.load("manright.gif")
    manup = pygame.image.load("manback.gif")
    tree = pygame.image.load("tree2.gif")
    tree1 = pygame.image.load("tree1.gif")
    tree2 = pygame.image.load("tree2.gif")
    rocka = pygame.image.load("rock.gif")
    rockb = pygame.image.load("rock.gif")
    rockc = pygame.image.load("rock.gif")
    border = pygame.image.load("iborder.gif")
    border1 = pygame.image.load("iborder1.gif")
    border2 = pygame.image.load("iborder2.gif")
    bg = pygame.image.load("bg.png")
    islot = pygame.image.load("islot.gif")
    i1 = pygame.image.load("inventory.gif")
    i2 = pygame.image.load("idown.png")
    i = pygame.image.load("bar.png")
    top = pygame.image.load("top.png")
    woodmat3 = pygame.image.load("woodmat3.png")
    woodmat6 = pygame.image.load("woodmat6.png")
    woodmat9 = pygame.image.load("woodmat9.png")
    rockmat2 = pygame.image.load("rockmat2.png")
    rockmat4 = pygame.image.load("rockmat4.png")
    rockmat6 = pygame.image.load("rockmat6.png")

    gameexit = False
    while not gameexit:

        win.fill(green)
        win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        win.blit(tree, (xtree, ytree))
        win.blit(tree1, (xtree1, ytree1))
        win.blit(tree2, (xtree2, ytree2))
        win.blit(rocka, (xrock, yrock))
        win.blit(rockb, (xrock1, yrock1))
        win.blit(rockc, (xrock2, yrock2))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameexit = True
        win.blit(man, (x, y))
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        movespeed = 5
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 5:
            x -= movespeed
            win.blit(manleft, (x + 10, y + 2))
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            x += movespeed
            win.blit(manright, (x, y))
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            y -= movespeed
            win.blit(manup, (x + 5, y + 5))
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            y += movespeed
            win.blit(man, (x, y - 5))
        if x == 400 and y == 140 and keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            xtree = 1000
            if xtree == 1000:
                woodmat += 1

        if x == 100 and y == 350 and keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            xtree1 = 1000
            if xtree1 == 1000:
                woodmat += 1

        if x == 600 and y == 200 and keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            xtree2 = 1000
            if xtree2 == 1000:
                woodmat += 1

        if x == 225 and y == 200 and keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            xrock = 1000
            if xrock == 1000:
                rockmat += 1

        if x == 700 and y == 365 and keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            xrock1 = 1000
            if xrock1 == 1000:
                rockmat += 1

        if x == 410 and y == 325 and keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            xrock2 = 1000
            if xrock2 == 1000:
                rockmat += 1

        win.blit(i, (200, 530))
        win.blit(top, (100, 2))

        def openinventory():
            global w
            win.blit(border, (10, 10))
            win.blit(border, (770, 10))
            win.blit(border1, (10, 270))
            win.blit(border1, (770, 280))
            win.blit(border2, (10, 590))
            win.blit(border2, (10, 10))
            win.blit(border2, (10, 250))
            win.blit(border2, (15, 270))
            win.blit(islot, (20, 20))
            win.blit(islot, (20, 100))
            win.blit(islot, (20, 175))
            win.blit(islot, (90, 20))
            win.blit(islot, (90, 100))
            win.blit(islot, (90, 175))
            win.blit(islot, (160, 20))
            win.blit(islot, (160, 100))
            win.blit(islot, (160, 175))
            win.blit(i1, (240, 20))
            win.blit(border, (230, 10))
            win.blit(i2, (14, 270))

            if woodmat == 1:
                win.blit(woodmat3, w)
                if w > (10, 10) and w > (200, 0):
                    w = (20, 455)
            if woodmat == 2:
                win.blit(woodmat6, w)
                if w > (10, 10) and w > (200, 0):
                    w = (20, 455)
            if woodmat == 3 or woodmat > 3:
                win.blit(woodmat9, w)
                if w > (10, 10) and w > (200, 0):
                    w = (20, 455)
            if rockmat == 1:
                win.blit(rockmat2, (100, 455))
            if rockmat == 2 or rockmat > 2:
                win.blit(rockmat4, (100, 455))
            if rockmat == 3 or rockmat > 3:
                win.blit(rockmat6, (100, 455))

        if keys[pygame.K_e]:
            openinventory()

        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.delay(30)
        clock.tick(60)


game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

i also apologize if the answer was very simple yet i was a big idiot
im pretty new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a global state variable `door_open = False` before the main loop, set the state when <kbd>e</kbd> is pressed:

```py
door_open = False

gameexit = False
while not gameexit:

    # [...]

    if keys[pygame.K_e]:
        door_open = True
    if door_open:
        openinventory() 

   # [...]
```

The `door_open` is ste `True` and keeps its state. If you want to "close" the door  you've to set `door_open = False`, e.g. close the door when <kbd>c</kbd> is pressed:

```py
if keys[pygame.K_c]:
    door_open = False
```

Note, you can do this by an event (e.g. `pygame.KEYDOWN`) in the event loop, too:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        gameexit = True
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_e:
            door_open = True
```

Comment: hey after doing this my function completely broke down, idk why, edit: nvm i fixed it

Comment: @AndromedaSource I'm pleased to help. Thank you. You're welcome.